# Custom unobtrusive validation for list of complex type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, unobtrusive-validation

Hey I was wondering if anyone could help me with some custom validation. The basic idea behind this is that when filling out a form a user is provided with several checkbox options where at least one has to be selected.

I have got the server side validation working fine but I'm a bit stumped on how to make this validate user input on the client as well.

I have the following ViewModel:

```
[CustomAttributes.AtLeastOneListItemSelected(ErrorMessage="You must select at least one game")]
public List<Game> GamesAppliedFor { get; set; }

.
.
.

public class Game
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

In another project I have my custom validation attributes and the 'AtLeastOneListItemSelected' has the following code:

```
public class AtLeastOneListItemSelected : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (value is IEnumerable)
        {
            foreach (var property in (IEnumerable)value)
            {
                var selectedProperty = property.GetType().GetProperty("Selected");

                if (selectedProperty != null)
                {
                    return (bool)selectedProperty.GetValue(property, null);
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        yield return new ModelClientValidationRule
        {
            ErrorMessage = ErrorMessage,
            ValidationType = "atleastone"
        };
    }
```

And last but not least my view contains the following:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.GamesAppliedFor, new { @class = "col-md-4 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-4">                            
            @foreach (var game in Model.GamesAppliedFor.Select((value, index) => new { index, value}))
                {
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.GamesAppliedFor[game.index].ID)
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.GamesAppliedFor[game.index].Selected, new {
                                                       id = Model.GamesAppliedFor[game.index].ID,
                                              })

                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.GamesAppliedFor[game.index].Title)
                         </label>
                    </div>
                }
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.GamesAppliedFor)
            </div>
        </div>
```

Now I was going to work on adding in the necessary jquery code for the custom attribute but something that completely slipped my mind was that I'm not outputting the List to the screen - just the properties within it and as such my current approach won't work.

My question is really how would you recommend I set up the client validation to work on the selected property as I cannot put the data annotation on the property itself - only the class as not all of them are mandatory.

Any suggestions are welcome. Thank you.

Comment: Shot answer is you cant using `IClientValidatable` because you do not (and should not) be generating a form control for `GamesAppliedFor` therefore `jquery.validate.unobtrusive` cannot add rules to the validator. Write you own script that handles the submit event, check that at least one checkbox is checked and cancel the submit and display a message  if not.

Comment: Ah I thought this might have been the case - thank you for the suggestion I'll write my own handler for this. Cheers!